# How to reference a variable within a proc in another proc

Tags: tcl

I have a proc that evaluates an expr and appends to a particular list locally

```
proc a {} {
set mylist ""
set out [expr...
lappend mylist $out
}
```

I want to use the "mylist" list outside of the "a" proc without declaring it as global or without returning that list from within the proc using "return mylist". How do I go about doing that. I have two use cases, Use the variable within another proc:

```
proc b {} {
do something with the "mylist" from proc a
}
```

Use case 2 :

```
Just use it outside the proc [Not within another proc]
```

Comment: There is no real difference between your "scenarios" (from a Tcl POV, using `upvar`).

Comment: Please take a moment to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

The "mylist" variable only exists as long as proc a is being executed. Whenever a proc finishes, all its local variables are cleaned up.

As long as `a` is in progress, you can access its variables using the `upvar` command.

For example: if you call `b` from `a`, `b` can access "mylist" using:

```
upvar 1 mylist othervar
puts $othervar
```

However, it is usually better practice to pass the variable (or at least its name) between procs, or make it a global or namespace variable.

Comment: Local variables are _unset_ when the procedure exits. In particular, this means that if you put an unset trace on them, that is called when the procedure exits. (Note that I don't really recommend putting _any_ traces on local variables, not if you want accesses to them to be fast, but unset traces are occasionally very useful in conjunction with automatic variable removal.)

Comment: The requestor wrote: "without declaring it as global". One should note that `upvar` and `global` can be equivalent, depending on the call context of the `proc` containing `upvar` (or how `upvar` is used from therein: `global` equiv `upvar #0`). That said, without using `global` or `upvar`, one would use a fully qualified variable name (`set ::mylist ...`) or a namespaced variable?

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm

**Sample code snippet:**

```
proc foo {ref_var} {
  upvar $ref_var local_var
  # do some operatins
  lappend local_var 20
}

proc bar {} {
  set a [list 10]
  puts "Before: $a"
  foo a
  puts "After: $a"
}

# nested proc
bar

# without proc
set c [list 30]
puts "Initial: $c"
foo c
puts "Final: $c"
```

**Output:**

```
Before: 10
After: 10 20
Initial: 30
Final: 30 20
```

Comment: Maybe better point to an up-to-date resource, and not one of an unmaintained Tcl version: https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm?